# Any Grease Pencil Edit Mode setting to only select points inside selection rectangle, ignoring fills?

Tags: selection-tools, grease-pencil

After following these steps...

- Create a grease pencil object
- Draw a stroke with a fill
- Enter edit mode
- Activate the 'Select Box' tool
- Set the Select mode to 'Select only points' (keyboard '1')
- Draw a selection box that contains the filled area but doesn't include any of the points of the stroke

...I expected:

- No points would be selected

...but actually:

- All points are selected

I'm finding this makes it difficult in situations where one stroke is inside of another, for example selecting some points of the inner stroke in the attached GIF. **Is there any setting that lets the simple rectangle selection ignore fills?**

The ctrl-alt-rightmouse lasso selection seems to ignore fills in the way that I want but rectangles are easier for me most of the time.

Thank you

[image: Demonstration of not being able to select just the points inside the rectangle, where the selection also includes points attached to the fills under the box]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the material tab and lock the fill material, so to make its points unselectable.

[image]

If the two strokes share the same material, activate the strokes selection mode, so that clicking on one point will select the whole stroke.

[image]

In case of need, select the background fill strokes, move them into a new layer and lock the layer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping to find a way to select points without having to lock/unlock/move other strokes.

Comment: Re-reading this, I guess the solution you suggest works specifically when you have one material for fills and another material for strokes, rather than one material with both a fill and a stroke.